# Jade template rendering tags without order

Tags: node.js, pug

I have this `jade` file:

```
- if (transactions != undefined)
    table
        th Site Name
        th Deadline
        th Delete Transaction

        each item in transactions
            tr
                td= item.item_name
                td
                    span(id='countdown'+item.timeout)= item.timeout
                td
                    span(style='cursor: pointer;', onclick='deleteTransaction('+item.uniqueId+')')= "X"

        button(id='confirmButton', onclick='confirm();', value="Confirm", name="Confirm")= "Confirm"
```

My question is very simple: when rendering all this stuff, the `jade` compiler renders the button on top of the table, and I would like it to be rendered after the table is shown. I searched through the doc once again, but I couldn't find anything of interest there. Can someone help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your indentation is such that the `button` will be inside the `table`. "De-dent" it one step to the left and you should be fine:

```
- if (transactions != undefined)
    table
        th Site Name
        th Deadline
        th Delete Transaction

        each item in transactions
            tr
                td= item.item_name
                td
                    span(id='countdown'+item.timeout)= item.timeout
                td
                    span(style='cursor: pointer;', onclick='deleteTransaction('+item.uniqueId+')')= "X"

    button(id='confirmButton', onclick='confirm();', value="Confirm", name="Confirm")= "Confirm"
```

Comment: Thanks. I was so in deep in the problem, trying to figure out what was wrong with the compilation of the loop that I didn't even see that one `tab`.